# Date Section Titles don't work

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a problem on a tableview with section by date.
I took the Apple example : [DateSectionTitles](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Introduction/Intro.html)

I don't care about year. I ust need month and day.
So I adapt my code like that :

In my CoreData class :

```
- (NSString *)sectionIdentifier {
[self willAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];
NSString *tmp = [self primitiveSectionIdentifier];
[self didAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];
NSLog(@"!Temp");
if (!tmp) {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:[self timeStamp]];
    tmp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ([components month]*100) + [components day]];
    [self setPrimitiveSectionIdentifier:tmp];
}
return tmp;}
```

And in my titleForHeaderInSection method in my main controller :

```
NSInteger month = numericSection / 100;
NSInteger day = numericSection - (month * 100);

NSString *titleString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %d",day, month];

return titleString;
```

But when I run my app I have this message :

**CoreData: error: (NSFetchedResultsController) A section returned nil value for section name key path 'sectionIdentifier'. Objects will be placed in unnamed section**

Do you know why ? 
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logically, that would happen if at this line of your code

```
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:
   (NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) 
   fromDate:[self timeStamp]];
```

`[self timeStamp]` returns an invalid `NSDate`. Check with `NSLog` statements if that is the case.

Comment: Nothing printed. It doesn't enter in - (NSString *)sectionIdentifier method :/

Comment: Well, great. You found the problem.

Comment: This is not solvable from the code you posted. Go back to where you create the data, check the sqlite persistent store, etc. until you hunt down the bug.

Answer (score 3):

One common mistake usually coding transient property for nsmanagedobject, is people forget to also "enable" transient property in the data model file (xcdatamodeld).

Comment: Enabling transient properties saved my day. Thanks!